# How can I determine if one rectangle is completely contained within another?

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

I have a theoretical grid of overlapping rectangles that might look something like this:

[image: grid layout]

But all I have to work with is a collection of Rectangle objects:

```
var shapes = new List<Rectangle>();
shapes.Add(new Rectangle(10, 10, 580, 380));
shapes.Add(new Rectangle(15, 20, 555, 100));
shapes.Add(new Rectangle(35, 50, 40, 75));
// ...
```

What I'd like to do is build a DOM-like structure where each rectangle has a ChildRectangles property, which contains the rectangles that are contained within it on the grid.

The end result should allow me to convert such a structure into XML, something along the lines of:

```
<grid>
  <shape rectangle="10, 10, 580, 380">
    <shape rectangle="5, 10, 555, 100">
      <shape rectangle="20, 30, 40, 75"/>
    </shape>
  </shape>
  <shape rectangle="etc..."/>
</grid>
```

But it's mainly that DOM-like structure in memory that I want, the output XML is just an example of how I might use such a structure.

The bit I'm stuck on is how to efficiently determine which rectangles belong in which.

**NOTE** No rectangles are partially contained within another, they're always completely inside another.

**EDIT** There will typically be hundreds of rectangles, should I just iterate through every rectangle to see if it's contained by another?

**EDIT** Someone has suggested Contains (not my finest moment, missing that!), but I'm not sure how best to build the DOM. For example, take the grandchild of the first rectangle, the parent does indeed contain the grandchild, but it shouldn't be a direct child, it should be the child of the parent's first child.

Comment: Re NOTE: then you only have to check one corner point.

Re EDIT: Yes.. but you may wish to mark each rectangle as processed so your outer loop can skip ones that have already been DOMified.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @BeemerGuy points out, `Rect.Contains` will tell you whether one rectangle contains another.  Building the hierarchy is a bit more involved...

There's an O(N^2) solution in which for each rectangle you search the list of other rectangles to see if it fits inside.  The "owner" of each rectangle is the smallest rectangle that contains it.  Pseudocode:

```
foreach (rect in rectangles)
{
    owner = null
    foreach (possible_owner in rectangles)
    {
        if (possible_owner != rect)
        {
            if (possible_owner.contains(rect))
            {
                if (owner === null || owner.Contains(possible_owner))
                {
                    owner = possible_owner;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // at this point you can record that `owner` contains `rect`
}
```

It's not terribly efficient, but it might be "fast enough" for your purposes.  I'm pretty sure I've seen an O(n log n) solution (it is just a sorting operation, after all), but it was somewhat more complex.

Comment: You can limit the search by sorting the rectangles by area from largest to smallest.  Then for any rectangle, it can not hold anything higher on the list (unless they are identical, and that is probably a weird corner case).

Answer (score 13):

Use the `Contains()` of a `Rectangle`.

```
Rectangle rect1, rect2;
// initialize them
if(rect1.Continas(rect2))
{
    // do...
}
```

**UPDATE**:
For future reference...
It's interesting to add that `Rectangle` also has `IntersectsWith(Rectangle rect)` in case you want to check if a rectangle partially collides with another rectangle.

Comment: Well that just blows all the other answers out of the water. Deleting mine now.

Comment: I think I speak for everyone here when I say, "D'Oh!"

Comment: Haha, thanks :-) I'm still not sure how I'd go about building the DOM with this though, even if a rectangle is contained within another, it might not be a direct child of it, it could be a grandchild, great grandchild etc..

Comment: @Matthew -- wish I know DOM manipulation, I just wanted to mention the `Contains()` method. Someone else should build on my answer.

Answer (score 4):

An average-case O(n log n) solution:

Think of your set of rectangles as a tree, where parent nodes "contain" the child nodes -- the same kind of thing as a DOM structure.  You'll be building the tree a rectangle at a time.

Make a dummy node to serve as the root of your tree.  Then, for each of your rectangles ("current_rect"), start with the root's children and work downwards until you find where it goes:

```
parent_node = root_node
sibling_nodes = [children of parent_node]

for this_node in sibling_nodes:
    if current_rect contains this_node:
        move this_node: make it a child of current_rect instead of parent_node
    elseif this_node contains current_rect:
        parent_node = this_node
        sibling_nodes = [children of parent_node]
        restart the "for" loop using new set of sibling_nodes

make current_rect a child of parent_node
```

The "contains" relation asks whether one rectangle contains the other.  "Parent", "child", and "sibling" are referring to the tree structure.

**EDITED**: Fixed a bug that would miss moving some nodes into current_rect.

Comment: An interesting idea. I think you can simplify your algorithm by starting with a list of nodes and an empty tree.  That would greatly reduce the restarts.

Comment: Actually, it would reduce the amount of processing you have to do after a restart.

Comment: @Jim: Actually, I was trying to express just that, if I understand what you're saying.  Start with a list and an empty tree, pull a node off the list and add it to the tree, and repeat until list is empty?  It's also possible I'm missing something big, since I don't know what you mean by restarts.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your pseudocode. By restart, I mean the processing that's implied by your line that reads, "restart the 'for' loop using new set of sibling_nodes."  Not a big deal, I upvoted your answer because it gives the basic idea and should be easy enough to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Check that each point in the rectangle is within the bounds of the other rectangles.
In .NET the Rectangle class has a .Contains(Point) method.  Or you can check the corner point coordinates againt the target rect's .Left, .Right, .Top, and .Bottom properties.

Answer (score 0):

pseudo code:

```
for i = 0 to rectangles.length - 2
 for j = i + 1 to rectangles.length - 1
     if rectangles[i].Contains(rectangles[j])
        //code here
}}}
```