# How to identify rectangles within rectangle in an image

Tags: c#, c, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if one rectangle is completely contained within another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270541/how-can-i-determine-if-one-rectangle-is-completely-contained-within-another)

How can i identify the outer rectangle and also determine that which rectangles are within the outer one.
Like here are four inner rectangles and one outer rectangle
[image: This the sample image]

Comment: Also decide if you're looking for a solution in C or C#